# Where would the commas go in a sentence like this?

Tags: punctuation

That was especially detrimental to me, who desiring to become a professional athlete, always avoided eating those types of foods.

When I try to look at what the main sentence is, it seems like it would be "That was especially detrimental to me." since you couldn't say "That was especially detrimental to me always avoided eating those types of foods."  If that's the case, then the second comma would need to be removed.  But the sentence just sounds awkward to we without the second comma.

I'm kind of making the sentence up, so I changed it a bit, and let's say the person is referring to a quota he was given of having to eat at Mc Donalds every day.

Comment: I need more context to make an assessment. What precedes 'That especially applied to me'?

Comment: The second comma is fine: it is the first which, being before rather than after *who*, is misplaced. (See what I did there?)

Comment: That first comma is needed, but the OP needs to provide more context.

Comment: It's a very awkward sentence and it needs some tweaking.

Comment: _That especially applied to me, who -- desiring to become a professional athlete -- always avoided eating those types of foods._ One comma, two dashes.

Comment: *'That especially applied to me. I always avoided eating those types of foods because I had the desire to become a professional athlete.'*

Comment: Now I was wondering if what TimLymington said was a viable option.  It does seem to solve the problem, but I just cant justify in my head placing a comma after the relative pronoun.  What would the main sentence be in that case?  "That was especially detrimental to me who always avoided those types of foods"?  But in that case, a comma is required before the "who," isn't it?

Comment: Required is relative. I like the comma before who, and would punctuate the sentence this way: *That was especially detrimental to me, who, desiring to become a professional athlete, always avoided eating those types of foods.* I think it reads well enough, but if three commas seem to be a bit much, it can be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

Another comma after who would help:

> That was especially detrimental to me, who, desiring to become a professional athlete, always avoided eating those types of foods.

Very Dickensian in its flavor that way though.

Answer (score 1):

As Joe has mentioned, you need to **add** another comma instead of removing one. This is because the clause "desiring to become a professional athlete" is explaining the word "who", and so one simplified version of the sentence would be:

> That was especially detrimental to me, who always avoided eating those types of food.

And then you expand on "who" part to be the complete sentence:

> That was especially detrimental to me, who, desiring to become a professional athlete, always avoided eating those types of food.

Comment: Good explanation of what I left out!